# Protractor - How to generate execution report or display the console.log messages in an output text file

Tags: javascript, android, jasmine, protractor, appium

I am using Protractor to test the Mobile hybrid app. I am using windows env. with javascript.

**I want to display the `console.log` messages in a separate text file after execution.**

or is there any way to generate the execution logs? 
I tried `resultJsonOutputFile` and http://eitanp461.blogspot.in/ or `console.push` message, but did not get the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want all protractor outputs, simply redirect the output:

```
protractor --option1=x --options2=y conf.js > /path/you/want/to/save/your/file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Hankduan for the quick response. Its working, it outputs to txt file, but not in proper format.                                  Can you pls explain what is option1=x and option2=y as i am new to protractor... Also, do you have any other report generation in protractor...

Comment: I just meant the normal configs you would use to run the test: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js. In terms of report generators, it depends on what frameworks you're using. If you're using jasmine, I believe https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters has the most, but you can simply google reporters for your framework