# How to write error logs from command prompt to a file in protractor

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I am using protractor-cucumber frame work. I am running my protractor script by the command `protractor conf.js` from the command prompt. I need to write the error logs from the command prompt to a external `.log` file after the execution of the protractor script. How can I catch this command prompt output to a file through the code. I need to **get the logs** in **both command prompt** and in an **external** `.log` file for which we should give the `.log` file path in the code).

Comment: Have you tried redirecting the standard output?

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27929555/2506522) post.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Redirecting the standard output is working for me, but what I need is if the test failed then only need to write the error logs to another file. I am able to identify whether the test failed or passed through the code, But I am not able to write the error logs in the command prompt to an another file through the code.

Comment: @betontalpfa, i am doing like appending the logs of each test run.I am using  protractor conf.js >> F:\logs\log.txt ,the logs are writing to the log.txt but i am not able to identify the date here.So how can we identify each logs by date?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jasmine, You should try below code

```
SpecDone: function(execResult) {
  for(var i = 0; i < execResult.failedExpectations.length; i++) {
    console.log('Failure: ' + execResult.failedExpectations[i].message);
    console.log(execResult.failedExpectations[i].stack);
  }
}
```